# SilverStripe i18n Textcollector Task not loading

Tags: internationalization, silverstripe

I'm using SilverStripe 3.4 and trying to translate my website. But on Windows I can't run the http://localhost/dev/tasks/i18nTextCollectorTask I get `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

I tried to create the translation files manually and added them to the mysite directory:

```
/lang/de_DE.php 
/lang/en_GB.php
```

containing the following code:

```
<?php

global $lang;
$lang['en_GB']['Header']['Contact'] = 'Get in Contact';
```

and in the Template:

```
<h5><%  _t('Header.Contact', 'Nehmen Sie Kontakt auf') %></h5>
```

but the Text is always in German ... Why is it not translating and why can't I open the Text Collector on Windows?

**Update**

I started the collector via cli

```
framework/sake dev/tasks/BetterI18nTextCollectorTask "targetlocale=de,en&module=themes/xxx&flush=1"
```

and there are two yml files in my theme/lang directory. But the text is still not translating.

de.yml:

```
de:
  Footer.ss:
    __IMAGE: '%2.2s'
  Header:
    __Contact: 'Nehmen Sie Kontakt auf'
```

en.yml

```
en:
  Footer.ss:
    __IMAGE: '%2.2s'
  Header:
    __Contact: 'Get in Contact'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To utilize the text collector task, you'd have to install [PHPUnit](https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit) 3.7.

You can add it as a dev-dependency via composer, so that it doesn't get included in a production environment:

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ~3.7
```

As an alternative to the text-collector task, you could also use the [better-i18n](https://packagist.org/packages/zauberfisch/silverstripe-better-i18n) module:

```
composer require --dev zauberfisch/silverstripe-better-i18n
```

It also requires PHPUnit, so that installation is a must.

Language files written in PHP have been deprecated quite a long time ago. You should switch to YAML based language files, which look like this:

```
# File stored in lang/en.yml
en:
  Header:
    Contact: 'Get in contact'
    # etc.
```

**Update:** There's also an updated syntax how to do translations in templates. You're using the old syntax that's going to be deprecated

This:

```
<h5><%  _t('Header.Contact', 'Nehmen Sie Kontakt auf') %></h5>
```

should become this:

```
<h5><%t Header.Contact 'Nehmen Sie Kontakt auf' %></h5>
```

Relevant [documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/i18n/#usage-in-template-files).

Comment: I recommend to use https://github.com/Zauberfisch/silverstripe-better-i18n which also saves $db fields and other "magic" stuff automatically for you to the language files. You need less code to define all your translations if you use the (quite undocumented) standards like db_FieldName for $db relations etc...

Comment: Note: The I18nTextCollectorTask also works with phpunit 4.x iirc

Comment: i installed phpunit via composer and get still ERR_CONNECTION_RESET wenn i open the collector task

Comment: @SergejAndropov Do you get anything in your php error logs?

Comment: [Thu Jul 21 09:56:44.721638 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3712:tid 540] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: @SergejAndropov That is really strange. And it only occurs when running the text-collector? I'd probably disable error-reporting when you run the text-collector then? Eg. by temporarily adding `error_reporting(0)` to your `_config.php`… see if that works.

Comment: i can start the collector via cygwin/cli "framework/sake dev/tasks/BetterI18nTextCollectorTask flush=1" but it generates no YAML files in my Theme folder only in mysite folder

Comment: @SergejAndropov the mysite folder is the default. You might have to specify the theme folder explicitly, something like: `sake dev/tasks/BetterI18nTextCollectorTask "targetlocale=de,en&module=themes/myTheme&flush=1`. See documentation: https://github.com/Zauberfisch/silverstripe-better-i18n#betteri18ntextcollectortask

Comment: Thank you i have now 2 yml files and updatet my question the text is still not translating ...